# Using sed command to print from the fourth to the second last line?

Tags: sed

How can I print from the fourth to the second last line using `sed` command?

Comment: "fourth" -- the fourth line (from the top) or the fourth-last line?

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -e '4,$!d' -e '$d'
```

Ex.

```
$ printf 'Line %d\n' {1..10} | sed -e '4,$!d' -e '$d'
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
Line 7
Line 8
Line 9
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
sed -e '1,3d;$d' file
```

- `1,3d` to delete first 3 lines.
- `$d` to delete last line.